# Need ready made tool or something like that to use for making my web application work offline

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee

Need ready made tool or something like that to use for making my web application work offline,
The problem with the Html5 option is that after clearing the cache the data stored in the browser's db get cleared so it could not work as my solution. I want some thing which could not be cleared even if cache is cleared. and  i cannot use the desktop application option too.

Comment: http://gears.google.com/ is deprecated.

Comment: thanks but,i knew that,and i cannot use that as it is depricated,

Answer (score 1):

- GEARS http://gears.google.com/
- ADOBE AIR ( so basically you can wrapped your HTML+JS+image to a AIR package ). But to be frank with you, to the user this option looks like a desktop application. http://www.adobe.com/products/air/

Comment: Thanks for your reply i will refer air if it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Will running a web container embedded solve your problem ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,It might solve it, but i need to see it first dude

Comment: What's with the "dude", dude?